# Why does this simple python program not work?

Tags: python

```
class F: 
    'test'
    def __init__(self, line, name, file, writef):
    self.line = line
    self.name = name
    self.file = file

def scan(self):
    with open("logfile.log") as search:
        #ignore this  part
        for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip();  # remove '\n' at end of line
        if num == line:
            self.writef = line

def write(self):
    #this is the part that is not working
    self.file = open('out.txt', 'w');
    self.file.write('lines to note:');
    self.file.close;
    print('hello world');

debug = F; 
debug.write
```

it executes with no errors but does nothing, tried many ways, searched online but i am the only one with this issue.

Comment: You forgot to call `F` and `write`. Just `F` and `debug.write` are essentially no operations. The same goes for `self.file.close` as well.

Comment: ...meaning you want to do `debug.write()` (with the brackets)

Comment: Also, all of your instance methods appear to be outside the class

Comment: You might need to fix your indentation as well, if it's wrong not just here but in your actual code as well.

Comment: You need to pass the constructor arguments when you make the Object of class F. What are you trying to do? Make your question clear.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is part of python syntax, so you'll need to develop a habbit of being consistent with it.
For the methods to be class methods, they need to be indented as such

Anyway, here's a modified version of your script that I have ran, and it works.

```
class F:
    'test'
    def __init__(self, line, name, file, writef):
        self.line = line
        self.name = name
        self.file = file
    def scan(self):
        with open("logfile.log") as search:
           #ignore this  part
            for line in search:
                line = line.rstrip();  # remove '\n' at end of line
                if num == line:
                    self.writef = line
    def write(self):
        # you should try and use 'with' to open files, as if you
        # hit an error during this part of execution, it will
        # still close the file
        with open('out.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('lines to note:');
        print('hello world');
# you also need to call the class constructor, not just reference
# the class. (i've put dummy values in for the positional args)
debug = F('aaa', 'foo', 'file', 'writef'); 
# same goes with the class method
debug.write()
```